# What's the most secure way to authenticate background queue workers using IdentityServer 4?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I have tasks that are placed onto a background queue for async processing. The standalone queue worker needs to authenticate to a separate API using IdentityServer 4, essentially "impersonating" the original user that triggered the task.

The two options I can see for doing this are:

1. Push the access and refresh tokens of the user into the queue's
   payload, and use these to authenticate when the task is picked up
   and executed. The main issue with this is that the queue's payload
   is stored in a database for an extended period of time, even after
   execution, meaning access and refresh tokens will be stored.
2. Try and recreate this type of user impersonation in IdentityServer
   4,
   https://www.moonlightbytes.com/blog/impersonation-in-identity-server-3.
   This would mean saving the original user's username in the queue's
   payload.

My questions are:

- Which one of these two options is preferable and more secure?
- Is there any other way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use [delegation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html), i.e. to push the *access token* (only) into the queue's payload (to identify the user later on) and use your worker's *ClientCredentials* to authenticate at the moment of the call.

Refresh token is definitely not to be shared. It is a property of an app it was requested for.

Comment: Without a refresh token, how would I deal with an expired access token? The queue worker is not guaranteed to run straight away, so there is a chance that the access token will expire before it's executed.

Comment: you do not need to keep that (original) token alive. in this particular case it's just a container for carrying the userId. a *signed* container. if you trust (and most likely you do) the entry point for the queue, that signing might be excessive and you can save just the id (name). at the other end of the queue you indeed have to get a fresh token anyway. that's a standard service operation and the standard solution is to use ClientCreds. embed userId into that new token or not - that's up to you - you can forward it as a parameter if you like. when you prefer to embed - still use delegation!

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting, but lets say I store have the original username in the queue payload, how can I then embed that in the client credentials token? I want to avoid sending it as a parameter.

Comment: you have to send it somehow anyway. and as that (token request) is a call to *token endpoint*, it should more (for the standard grant types) or less (for a custom one) follow the specification. actually token request format is less strict than authorize one, but could still use [`acr_values`](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/token.html) parameter for your custom data. you must not concern the security too much as it's server to server communication.

Comment: `push the access token (only) into the queue's payload (to identify the user later on) and use your worker's ClientCredentials to authenticate at the moment of the call.` But what about case where worker needs to do some action **on-behalf-of user** and not its worker identity. Let's say I'm saving file to user onedrive and after 24 hours I have to delete it. I put a message in a queue which is then picked up after 24h. Access token is already expired and I cannot do this action using application identity. In this case I have to store refresh token somewhere. Just an example.

Comment: @d_f I'm talking about slightly different scenario where IdentityServer is not used but you   wrote `Refresh token is definitely not to be shared. `. Take a look at the [MS Graph Task Api](https://docs.microsoft.com/graph/api/todotasklist-post-tasks). It can be called only with delegated permissions and not with app permissions. User once signed in in my application (I got his access and refresh token), setup his schedules and now every so often I have a background job which creates tasks for this specific user.  I dont see how I can achieve this without storing his refresh token somewhere.

Comment: @kamilz `refresh_token` is not to be shared anyway. I see the problem: the api from MS is not designed to be called from a job, so you need a workaround... in this specific case having a refresh token in the job could be the only solution... but it's definitely not the proper one. as for me, I would avoid collecting my users' refresh tokens (obtained from MS?) in a service. too risky. at least you have to think about requesting as few permissions (scopes) as possible (the only? to be able to call that scheduled task)