# Access tokens for long-running tasks

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect, refresh-token

**The hypothesis is this**:

A front-end app requests authentication using implicit flow and user is logged in. The app offers functionality for user to create a task/job that should perform a number of things at a scheduled point in the future and on users behalf. This might also be a long-running task spanning over hours (even days). The front-end app has its own client id (with implicit flow) while the service executing the scheduled task has a separate client id (and secret).

**Questions:**

- What should the front-end app pass on to the scheduled task so the service executing the scheduled task can authenticate as the original user?
- Assuming that the task should operate with a refresh token so it can get fresh access tokens when needed, how can it get the refresh token in the first place? The front-end app cannot pass the first one as refresh tokens are not supported in implicit flow and it would be issued to the wrong client even if it had been supported.

Comment: looks pretty similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58076186/1426685) one

Comment: Similar, yes, but it doesn't solve the problem I'm trying to describe. I can already now pass on user id or name to the task runner, but using client credentials will give it access token with no reference to the user, which will later on cause problems where the task runner is accessing resources where user authorization is required.

Comment: you missed the point: on the linked answer I suggested to put in the access token to *extract* userId later on. and *to use delegation* (based on client credentials) to get a fresh token *with the user inside* when it's time to. I see no difference with your "long running task"

Comment: sending userId as a plain parameter is just an alternative, but an absolutely valid one when you absolutely trust your service running the job and it's connection to the following api (for instance you can use a client certificate)

Comment: one more significant point in the linked answer was that the *refresh token* is not to be shared. so even you switch from implicit to code or hybrid to get a refresh token, it's aimed to be used with the only client and not to be sent to another (such as your job runner).

Comment: I do trust the service, but the point here is that steps to be executed should only run in the context of the original user, _not_ as ClientCredentials. So if the user at any point is disabled/deleted, the job would no longer be valid. Also the services accessed by the runner should log events as though it was the user running things manually, again - not as a trusted service.

And I did specify in my original post that I have no intention of sharing the refresh token, as that is not only a bad idea but not even allowed.

Comment: well, then I guess the delegation approach is still what you need. when a (task worker) client is retrieving a fresh access token it provides an old one (from the front) and it's a good time to ensure that the user's still valid. what you should skip at that point is checking the original token' expiration. IdSrv does exact the same when validating an old identity token on user signout.

Comment: In essence this is a service without user interaction, which means that client credentials suffices. The service has access to the resource, the resource can validate the user against the client request, so there's no need to change authorization. The problem here seems that the service uses the same endpoints as the UI client, which usually isn't the case as there isn't much overlap (different tasks). Instead of faking a user's access token, create seperate endpoints for the service and inject repositories that allow you to send the sub value as parameter or sub claim value for UI client.

Answer (score 0):

A good idea would be to look at delegation. With this concept, your service could retrieve a new token that identifies itself as the user but with a special "act" claim that identifies the service.
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-token-exchange-16

Identity server does not have this be default anymore in version 4 but there are some examples out there on how to add it back in. This case would be pretty simple as you have said you can trust your service so all you really need is to tell IdentityServer that clientid is allowed to impersonate anyone
Here's an example https://www.daimto.com/identity-server-4-user-delegation/